# Nifi: How to generate a custom json object from csv

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a csv flow file as shown below.

```
id,version,status
SHIPMENT00020,0b730219321af938e85f3f185d6445d6da3dc790a1f6a8a6949de2441814e130,Created
SHIPMENT00024,92a2931dc69f89e9dadebf209da73965b8f5823b8eee21aa7c55123aeb95d56f,Created
```

I need to generate a json object in below format.

```json
{
 "id": "randomID-1",
 "acknowledge": {
 "SHIPMENT00020": "0b730219321af938e85f3f185d6445d6da3dc790a1f6a8a6949de2441814e130",
 "SHIPMENT00024": "92a2931dc69f89e9dadebf209da73965b8f5823b8eee21aa7c55123aeb95d56f"
 }
}
```

I have tried convertRecord processor which directly converts csv to json. So i am getting a list of objects. Is there any way to create a map of 'map<id,version> acknowledgement' to get the json generated in the above format.

Comment: What about using jolt to transform json to json?